# Js Regular expression for first name

Tags: javascript, regex, formvalidation.io

I am looking for a regular expression which fulfil below conditions

- Min 1 and Max 50 char
- No spaces at the beginning and ending of string
- Allow only one space, dot between 2 words.

I am using below expression which causes catastrophic backtracking issue.
Expression -

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:|['_\. ])([a-zA-Z]*(\.\s)?[a-zA-Z])+)*$/
```

How can I prevent this issue?

Comment: Try [`/^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z]+(?:['_.\s][a-z]+)*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/TmJTBD/3).

Comment: I updated my question, underscore will be there in pattern

Comment: It would be good to have a set of test strings. Try them at https://regex101.com/r/TmJTBD/3

Comment: /^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z]+(?:['_.\s][a-z]+)*$/i. This worked for me . Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 9):

You may use

```
/^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z]+(?:['_.\s][a-z]+)*$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TmJTBD/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,50}$)` - there must be 1 to 50 chars in the string
- `[a-z]+` - 1  or more ASCII letters
- `(?:['_.\s][a-z]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `['_.\s]` - a `'`, `_`, `.` or whitespace
  - `[a-z]+` - 1  or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string
- `/i` - a case insensitive modifier.